# php while loop not showing results

Tags: php

Can someone please point out what I'm sure is a stupidly obvious error in my code? The string "string" in my while loop is displaying the correct amount of times but not the results in row[0].

```
if (!isset($_GET['city']) & !isset($_GET['county'])) {
    $getResults = "SELECT DISTINCT region FROM `locations` WHERE country = 'England'";
    echo "No region or county set";

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($getResults)) {
        echo "Found results";

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "string";
            echo $row[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In dubious cases, when something is not quite right, remember to use the **var_dump()** function to echo the variables in question... And then you save yourself valuable time figuring things like this out oon your own.

Comment: You're fetching `assoc` but trying to display as though the array is `enumerated`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the contents of the $row array dump it out like so `var_dump($row)`.

I'm guessing you just need `echo $row['region']` rather than `$row[0]`

Answer (score 2):

You are using `fetch_assoc()` but you try to access the row using a index numbers.

Use `fetch_row()` instead.